# Matlab GUI Error Value

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide

I have a MATLAB program that I am doing a GUI for. It has several inputs and outputs and all are working fine except for one and I have no idea why.

The input is Area_Cov, this input is not changed in the code, it is just used.

In the GUI, I used an edit box for it, named its tag "Area_Cov"
This is the edit box call back function, and i've used the same code for many other boxes, which are working fine.

```
function Area_Cov_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to Area_Cov (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Hints: get(hObject,'String') returns contents of Area_Cov as text
%        str2double(get(hObject,'String')) returns contents of Area_Cov as a double

v = (get(hObject,'String')); %get recently entered string

if (str2num(v) <= 0)
  waitfor(warndlg('Area value has to be real','!! Warning !!'))
         (warndlg('The value will be set to 10452','!! Warning !!'))
         set(hObject,'String',10452);
else
  Area_Cov = handles.Area_Cov; %update saved value
end

 x = get(handles.Area_Cov,'String'); 
 if isempty(x)
   waitfor(warndlg('Must specify Area Covered','!! Warning !!'))
         (warndlg('Value set to 10452','!! Warning !!'))
          set(hObject,'String',10452);
end


guidata(hObject,handles)
```

When i push the button calculate, I have the following concerning Area_Cov

```
Area_Cov=handles.Area_Cov;
assignin('base', 'Area_Cov', Area_Cov);
```

When i run the code, and press the push button, everything seems to be working fine.
But when i try to check the value of Area_Cov in matlab, i always get the value 259.0017

I deleted the box, wrote it again, changed Area_Cov to Area_Covered, check the matlab code, and there isn't anywhere in the code, or the GUI code, where Area_Cov has an input other than the edit box, and nowhere were this value is equal to 259.0017.
Furthermore, if i don't change the value in the box, which is 10452 at first, the value will stay the same, otherwise it will change to 259.0017 only.

The code is working fine for many other boxes, so I don't think it is the issue.

Anyone had this problem before ? HELP

Answer (score 1):

`Area_Cov = handles.Area_Cov;` just sets `Area_Cov` to the *handle*, not the contents of the handle.  (259.0017 is a likely numerical representation of this).  What you presumably want to set it to is the numerical value represented by `str2num(v)`, which you use to check validity of the input and then never use again.

It's also not clear to me why you're calling `get` twice and what the difference between  `x` and `v` might be.

Comment: even if i delete all the code in the callback of Area_Cov and only add Area_Cov = handles.Area_Cov , I am still getting the value 259.0017
When i use v instead of x, which i think are the same, i am not getting the same result from the function isempty, but that's not the problem that i need to solve now , can be overlooked atm

Comment: I am saying that you **should not** do the line `Area_Cov = handles.Area_Cov`, as it doesn't give you the value of the contents of the box.  You should do something like `Area_Cov = str2num(v))` instead.

Comment: but why isn't it working only for the Area_Cov, i have more than 5 other functions with the same type and same code but different names that are working just fine

Comment: @Necro1992 I don't believe that.

Comment: @Necro1992 You either have made a mistake in the other code or you are mistaken about the content of the other code. There is no way that you can get the value of a box or other GUI object like that.  See the section *Hints* at the top of your code, which I guess your teacher/lecturer wrote?

Comment: @nkjt nope the hints are automatically produced by GUIDE when generating the .m file of a .fig file.

Comment: I'm learning it alone, i can send you the files to tests them and you can see that I am getting it :D I will keep on trying to fix it

Comment: @Benoit_11 Ah, I do my stuff by hand so didn't know.